# command line error "no volume specified"

Tags: terminal, command-line

Can't understand why I get this response when running this bless command, can someone please explain or suggest how to fix. Note: the volume syntax/path was copied exactly from the output after dragging location from the volume root folder into the Terminal window:

```
Last login: Thu Jan 10 10:27:52 on ttys000
xxxx:~ xxxx$ su - xxxxx
Password:
xxxx:~ xxxx$ sudo bless --file /Volumes/ML2/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
Password:
No volume specified
xxxx:~ xxxxx$
```

Answer (score 2):

The `bless` command has be deprecated. Basically, the command is not compatible with APFS. Other replacements are:

- The `systemsetup` command. Use options `-setstartupdisk`, `-getstartupdisk` and `liststartupdisks`.
- The Mac Startup Manager. Basically hold down the option key at startup. To make an OS the default, hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key before selecting.
- The Startup Disk pane in the System Preferences application.
- The third party [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Boot Manager. This can be installed without disabling SIP.

However, I you still want to use the `bless` command, then syntax is shown below.

```
sudo bless --device /dev/disk0sX --setBoot
```

Where positive integer `X` can be found by entering the command given below.

```
mount | grep "/Volumes/ML2 "
```

I tested this command by boot to Yosemite on a 2007 iMac. I used the `bless` command to select `El Capitan` as the default operating system to boot.

> Note: Yosemite does not use System Integrity Protection (SIP)

If selecting a BIOS booting Windows (or other) operating system, be sure to include the following option.

```
--legacy
```

Below is the result when trying to use the `bless` command from High Sierra with SIP enabled. The machine is a 2011 iMac.

```
Marlin:~ davidanderson$ sudo bless --device /dev/disk0s6 --setboot
Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc
```

Below is the result when trying to use the `bless` command from El Capitan with SIP enabled. The machine is a 2007 iMac.

```
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ sudo bless --device /dev/disk0s5 --setboot
Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc
```

Comment: Thanks, know how to get into boot manager, but the issue is missing blessed system file on a 10.8. Am running these commands to the 10.8 target root folder mounted in 10.12. The system file needing blessing is 10.8. Does that change things?

Comment: @VB23: This is why OP's need to include the computer model/year and the versions of OS X/macOS. I suppose in your case the `bless` command could still be used. Although, I would assume 10.8 would appear in the Startup Disk pane of System Preferences.

Comment: OK, so question remains even after running _sudo bless --mount /Volumes/ML2 --file /Volumes/ML2/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi_ system file remains unblessed. What else to try? Please see output from _sudo bless --info /Volumes/ML2_  in my answer/reply above._finderinfo[1]: 749497 => Blessed System File is <missing>_

Comment: @VB23: I believe you need to add -setBoot.

Comment: sudo bless --mount /Volumes/ML2 --file /Volumes/ML2/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi -setBoot
Password:
Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc

Comment: Wrong syntax? Where to add -setBoot? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ran _sudo bless --device /dev/disk1s7 --setBoot_, but get "Could not set boot device property." Need to disable SIP for this to work from 10.12?

Comment: @VB23 I get the same error message when SIP is enabled. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bless command usually get invoked with more parameters.

One is `--mount` to specify the volume. In your case it would be:

```
sudo bless --mount /Volumes/ML2 --file /Volumes/ML2/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
```

Other frequently used parameters are:

- `--setBoot`
- `--folder`

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not an answer, but not getting proper formatting from "add a comment", so using the answer option. Don't know my way around here all that well.

The command you provided, sudo bless --mount /Volumes/ML2 --file /Volumes/ML2/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi, ran without objection, however still no system file blessed:

sudo bless --info /Volumes/ML2
finderinfo[0]: 612282 => Blessed System Folder is /Volumes/ML2/System/Library/CoreServices
finderinfo[1]: 749497 => Blessed System File is 
finderinfo[2]:      0 => Open-folder linked list empty
finderinfo[3]:      0 => No alternate OS blessed file/folder
finderinfo[4]:      0 => Unused field unset
finderinfo[5]: 612282 => OS X blessed folder is /Volumes/ML2/System/Library/CoreServices

Comment: Perhaps a misunderstanding here: --setBoot flag appears to be meant to make a volume the startup disk -- no need to do this from the command line--easily done from sys prefs. Just interested in blessing the boot.efi file--missing in bless info. After I ran the --setBoot command, with SIP disabled, I lost the current startup disk (Have 10.12 and 10.6 on internal partitions --- the ML 10.8 is on a partition on an external drive.) When it lost the 10.12 startup disk, kept booting to the 10.6 (with the external quit.) Had to do a PRAM reset and then restore the startup disk to the original 10.12.

Comment: I do not believe what you trying to do is normally done on Mac computers. It may not evenly be possible to do what you are trying to do on a Mac computer. The closest you are going to get would be to install rEFInd. Instead of using the `bless` command to edit the PRAM, you could edit the `refind.conf` text file.